# PHP Error: Undefined index: id

Tags: php, associative-array

Previously my code looked like this:

```
for ($i=0, $n=sizeof($values); $i<$n; $i++) {
  $field .= '<option value="' . xtc_parse_input_field_data($values[$i]['id'], array('"' => '&quot;')) . '"';
  if ($default == $values[$i]['id']) {
    $field .= ' selected="selected"';
  }

  $field .= '>' . xtc_parse_input_field_data($values[$i]['text'], array('"' => '&quot;', '\'' => '&#039;', '<' => '&lt;', '>' => '&gt;')) . '</option>';
}
```

Following some advice I changed it to:

```
if (is_array($values) && count($values) > 0) {
  foreach ($values as $value) {
    $field .= '<option value="' . xtc_parse_input_field_data($value['id'], array('"' => '&quot;')) . '"';
    if ($default == $value['id']) {
      $field .= ' selected="selected"';
    }

    $field .= '>' . xtc_parse_input_field_data($value['text'], array('"' => '&quot;', '\'' => '&#039;', '<' => '&lt;', '>' => '&gt;')) . '</option>';
  }
}
```

But the error remains:

> Notice: Undefined index: id in E:\xampp\htdocs\testshop\inc\xtc_draw_pull_down_menu.inc.php

What's causing this error?

Comment: Did you try `var_dump($values)`?

Comment: Also: does the error message contain a line number? If so, which line is it?

Comment: I'd like to remind everyone that this question is close to 2 years old before asking for any clarification. Chances are that OP will not be able to tell you what `$values` looked like.

Comment: In the code shown, this error could only come from two lines, both of which make the same access `$value['id']`.  The way this code is structured, the values array needs to be a numeric array of associative arrays.  For example, created with `$values[] = array( "id" => "blah", "text" => "bleah");`

Comment: Yes, I was just cleaning this up for future visitors because it was a top result from a google search I did.

Comment: @JohnHascall I believe the regular reference we use is [PHP: “Notice: Undefined variable” and “Notice: Undefined index”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the warning basically does not have anything to do with the piece of code that you have pasted, rather it has to do with the fact that `$value` does not have an index named `id` in the first place. So in order to fix it you have to check at the source - the place where `$values` is generated/stored, to see why there are some values without id.

Having said that, in order to prevent the unwanted notice in your code you can add the following line to test if an index named `id` exists, before proceeding:

```
if(array_key_exists('id',$value)) {
   //do all your stuff
}
```

You can add this just below the line after `foreach ($values as $value) {` so that everything you do inside the loop only happens if `$value` has an `id` element.

However as stated earlier, if you expect every `$value` to definitely have an `id`, go back to the place where `$values` are generated and check whats going on there.